# Prompting for password when opening a Word/Excel etc document from library

Tags: password

When accessing SharePoint inside the network where the server is hosted, SharePoint works fine.  However, when the site is accessed outside of the network users are prompted for usernames and passwords when opening a Word/Excel document from the library.

Previously I have got around this by adding in the authforwardserverlist entry in the registry and it works a treat, but I am wondering if there is another way around this.

Comment: I think it is desired behavior as the user's windows is logon as another domain. The office program (word/excel) is logon as another domain, too.